# Adding two linear layout in scrollview the layout either shrink or compress. Here i am using layout_weight in them that's why the problem occurs

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-layout-weight

when i used the single linear layout in scrollview then the output and code is like that

Xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/disp_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disp_title"
                    style="@style/disTitleTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disp_cont"
                    style="@style/disdiscTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/disptextdes"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disp_readmore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="To read more click on this"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

output is:
[image]

But when i add another layout then code and output is look like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        //first linear layout
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/disp_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disp_title"
                    style="@style/disTitleTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disp_cont"
                    style="@style/disdiscTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/disptextdes"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disp_readmore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="To read more click on this"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            // when i add second linear layout then the first linear layout is varied,I don't know why
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/citispotterlogo"></ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

output is :
[image]

When i added the image in linear layout the first linear layout shrink I don't know why?
Please help me to solve this,I try to search this on google in stackoverflow but i don't find nothing about this. Can anybody solve this or give me some another approach for solving this problem.

So my final output is look like this
I have added two images which are in scrollview
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpJ9C.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhQoL.png)

Comment: What is your expected requirements. Can you clear?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use two Linear layouts here? I agree with @Md. Asaduzzaman it unclear on the result you are looking for

Comment: I need a scrollview in which one linear layout is showing the first output that you see in the photo, but when i add other layout the size of the layout varies because i use layout_weight. When i use some fix height then i get the proper linear layout but the output is different in different mobiles screen. Is there any method to solve this problem? or some different opinion to solve this problem. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: I don't have to use layout_height here, I set it to 0dp and adding a layout_weight in it. So is there any other method to give height because different mobile have different size so if i give some specific height then this the problem for other size mobile

Comment: I have edit the code please check @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: you also please check @Shawn

Comment: @nitesh, I asked you earlier, what do you want? Can you add your required image then?

Comment: I have added the final output @Md.Asaduzzaman. you can check it and then tell me what are things i need to add. In second layout i just added image for check the scrollview but it shrink. But in the output you see there is no shrinkness

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">
```

This LinearLayout has height which is match_parent, you should have used wrap_content or use a fixed height so that the second layout must be visible

Comment: I can't used fixed height because different screen have different size. So there is a problem in that, that's why i use layout weight . Is there any other method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This layout uses a **weightSum** in the first linear layout when you add the last LinearLayout you do not include a weight for it. This is causing the UI to render incorrectly.

I've included a couple of option solution for you both should do the job.

### Option 1

change the weighted sum in the first LinearLayout to 11 and then add a weight value of 1 to the last LinearLayout.

### Option 2

Add a weighted value to the last LinearLayout but you will need to adjust the rest of the weighted values so it equals weight sum in the first LinearLayout (10).

### LayoutWeight Review

LinearLayout supports assigning a weight to individual children with the android:layout_weight attribute. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. The default weight is zero.

Comment: When i use the option 1, the size of the first layout is more expanded. And i give second linear layout as layout_weight =1 and layout_height=0dp;